# PyCharm PyTypeChecker complaining about type signature when updating set with set comprehension

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is a minimal example:

```py
from typing import Set


def f() -> Set[str]:
    xs = set()
    xs.update({x for x in ["a", "b"]})
    return xs
```

PyCharm's PyTypeChecker will complain about the function's type signature:

```
Expected type 'Set[str]', got 'Set[set]' instead
```

If I replace the set comprehension `{x for x in ["a", "b"]}` by set value `{"a", "b"}`, there is no warning.

Why is that so ?

I'm using Python 3.8 and PyCharm 2021.2 Community Edition.

Comment: If I replace `update` by the `|=` operator, it does not complain anymore. I will use that instead then.

Comment: The corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49951